# SilverStripe data not showing in the template

Tags: php, silverstripe

I tried this but can not output existing data in my database server.

**Page.ss** (Layout directory)

```
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">
    <article>
        <div>
            <% loop $LatestMyData %>
              $Data1
            <% end_loop %>
        </div>
        <div class="content">$Content</div>
    </article>
    $Form
    $CommentsForm
</div>
```

**MyData.php** (mysite/code directory)

```
class MyData extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Data1' => 'Varchar(30)'
    );
}

class MyData_Controller extends Controller {
    public function LatestMyData($count = 1) {
        return MyData::get()
            ->limit($count);
    }   
}
```

I tried to build database with `/dev/build` and flush cache with `?flush=all` but still no output. Does anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: Did you create a page? How are you trying to display the data object? Looking at our example you want MyData to be a page, then you should extend MyData from Page and MyData_Controller from Page_Controller

Comment: @Greg want i wanted to do is extend a DataObject and display it on a Page, does that makes sense?

Comment: To display DataObject on a Page, you should use relation from the page, like has_one or has_many. It depends what you want to be your 'Data1' property. It might be a property of the page itself. and `LatestMyData` method will work in your Page_Controller with your Page.ss (DataObjects usually have no controllers, and provide data for pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LatestMyData` function should be in `Page_Controller` instead of `MyData_Controller` as this is the controller that a page template will call.

The `MyData` object also needs to be controlled in the CMS in some way. This can be done either through a ModelAdmin or a GridField with a relationship to a page.

Here is a working example showing one way to do this using a one to many relationship between `Page` and `DataItem`:

**DataItem.php**

```
class DataItem extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(30)'
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Page' => 'Page'
    );
}
```

**Page.php**

```
class Page extends SiteTree {
    private static $has_many = array(
        'DataItems' => 'DataItem'
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $dataItemsField = GridField::create(
            'DataItems',
            'Data Items',
            $this->DataItems(),
            GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
        );
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.DataItems', $dataItemsField);

        return $fields;
    }

}

class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    function LatestDataItems($limit = 1) {
        return $this->DataItems()->limit($limit);
    }
}
```

**templates/layout/Page.ss**

```
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">
    <article>
        <div>
        <% loop $LatestDataItems %>
            $Title
        <% end_loop %>
        </div>
        <div class="content">$Content</div>
    </article>
    $Form
    $CommentsForm
</div>
```

If we only want the first `DataItem` object we can can call `$DataItems.First` instead of our `LatestDataItems` function:

**templates/layout/Page.ss**

```
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">
    <article>
        <% if $DataItems.First %>
        <% with $DataItems.First %>
        <div>
            $Title
        </div>
        <% end_with %>
        <% end_if %>
        <div class="content">$Content</div>
    </article>
    $Form
    $CommentsForm
</div>
```